# PyTest : how to run a specific script with specific marker

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

What i'm trying to achieve is to run a python test script but i want to control which tests are being run through `@pytest.mark` fixture. What i did so far is:

1. Define the markers in `pytest.ini` file like this:

   `[pytest]`

   `markers=[omni,milestone,release]`
2. In the test module script i defined 2 test methods:

   - test_1 marked with : `@pytest.mark.omni` marker
   - test_2 marked with : `@pytest.mark.release` marker
     I'm trying to execute the code in the following manner: at the end of the module i've placed this piece of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        import pytest
        junit_path = os.path.join(tmp_folder, 'reports', 'Junit_p1_' + os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'] + '_' + time.strftime( "%d%m%Y_%H%M%S") + '.xml')
        exit_code = pytest.main(['-vv', '--cache-clear', 'p1.py', '--durations=0', '--junitxml', junit_path, '--tb' ,'long']) # full execution
        sys.exit(exit_code)
```

i'm invoking the module by calling

```
python p1.py
```

I'm trying to figure out where I can add the marker filter in the side the `pytest.main` invocation in order to run specific markers from the tests

Comment: `pytest.main([..., '-m', 'release'])`?

Comment: @hoefling cool, i added those flags to the array and it worked, thanks